# EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file about streamlit

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit

I am using streamlit version v0.68 and currently working on CSV file for data analysis.

```
st.title('Report Analysis')
uploaded_file = st.file_uploader("Choose a file")
if uploaded_file is not None:
    data = pd.read_csv(uploaded_file, low_memory=False)
    st.write(data.shape)
```

First it works, but if I rerun the program in my localhost it gives me the error:

```
EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
Traceback:

File "D:\My Programs\Projects\ReportAnalysis\venv\lib\site-packages\streamlit\script_runner.py", line 324, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "D:\My Programs\Projects\ReportAnalysis\epl\app.py", line 9, in <module>
    data = pd.read_csv(uploaded_file, low_memory=False)
File "D:\My Programs\Projects\ReportAnalysis\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 686, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
File "D:\My Programs\Projects\ReportAnalysis\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 452, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
File "D:\My Programs\Projects\ReportAnalysis\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 946, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
File "D:\My Programs\Projects\ReportAnalysis\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1178, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
File "D:\My Programs\Projects\ReportAnalysis\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 2008, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 540, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
```

How to handle this error?

Comment: what happens when you remove the brackets of head()

Comment: If I update anything in the program and rerun it. it shows the same error.

Comment: From your error it seems that it is coming from the reading of the file and not the writing of the file. What is "line 9" in your code?

Comment: `data = pd.read_csv(uploaded_file, low_memory=False)` this is line 9. I had only written the code and not the imports here.

Comment: The error occurs even without `st.write(data.head())` when you rerun the script

Comment: If i rerun the code it shows the error.

Answer (score 7):

According to [this post from the Streamlit community page](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/emptydataerror-no-columns-to-parse-from-file/6247), it is because they are returning the same buffer on the second time the app refreshes. Since pd.read_csv depletes the buffer, the second time you call read_csv will return no rows.

Adding a `seek(0)` to reset the buffer worked for me.

e.g.

```
st.title('Report Analysis')
uploaded_file = st.file_uploader("Choose a file")
if uploaded_file is not None:
    uploaded_file.seek(0)
    data = pd.read_csv(uploaded_file, low_memory=False)
    st.write(data.shape)
```

Answer (score 2):

This problem only occurs with the new version v0.68.1. As a work-around, you can always go back to an older version, e.g. 0.66, using:
`pip install streamlit=0.66`

Answer (score 1):

This will help you. Works with the current version 0.69.1.

```
global train_upload
train_upload = st.file_uploader("Upload csv data", type=['csv'])
if (train_upload is not None):
    train_features = train_upload.read()
    train_features = str(train_features,'utf-8')
    train_features = StringIO(train_features)
    train_features = pd.read_csv(train_features)
    st.write(train_features)
```

Answer (score 0):

For Streamlit 1.5.0, I tried all of the suggested solutions and none of them worked. The workaround I found was to write the content to a temporary file and then read from it:

```
uploaded_file = st.file_uploader("Choose a file", type=["csv", "txt"])
content = StringIO(uploaded_file.getvalue().decode("utf-8")).read()
temp_filepath = f"/tmp/{uuid4()}"
with open(temp_filepath, "w") as f:
    f.write(content)
data = read_csv(temp_filepath)
```